# What does dollar sign do in scala

Tags: scala

When I was reading spark source code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/098be27ad53c485ee2fc7f5871c47f899020e87b/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala#L66), I saw code like `$(a_variable)`.
What does it mean?

I copy the code here:

```
  final val blockSize: IntParam = new IntParam(this, "blockSize",
    "Block size for stacking input data in matrices. Data is stacked within partitions." +
      " If block size is more than remaining data in a partition then " +
      "it is adjusted to the size of this data. Recommended size is between 10 and 1000",
    ParamValidators.gt(0))

  /** @group getParam */
  final def getBlockSize: Int = $(blockSize)
```

Comment: This surprises me to see. The use of dollar signs in identifiers is discouraged, though not actually illegal, in both Java and Scala, because the compiler uses `$` internally in generated code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That isn't special Scala syntax, it's a method name. In Scala `$` is a legal identifier. The method is inherited from the `org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param` trait.

See the [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/098be27ad53c485ee2fc7f5871c47f899020e87b/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala#L474).

Comment: The source is not very clear when saying "Gets the value of a param in the embedded param map or its default value". Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @PedroGordo The source is clearer when you realize that `$` is a shortcut to [`getOrDefault`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/098be27ad53c485ee2fc7f5871c47f899020e87b/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala#L467) which does exactly what it sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the dollar sign is usually used for string interpolation. What that means is that if I want to use a val(ue)/var(iable) inside a string (denoted with an `s` before the first double quotation), I can access such vals/vars using the `$` sign. Otherwise, we won't be able to use vals/vars inside a string since it would not know how to escape the string characters.

Example:

```
val favoriteFruit = "strawberry"
val strawberryCount = 12

println(s"My favorite fruit is ${favoriteFruit}. I've had ${strawberryCount} pieces today!") // string interpolation
```

In your case, however it seems that `$` is a shortcut to `getOrDefault` the var/val (as sourced by @Michael Zajac and @kingledion...gets the value/variable. If it does not exist, gets the default value/variable). Using `getOrDefault` may be a more robust solution in cases in which you expect the parameter to not always have a corresponding value, for which you can set a default value.