# In Scala, what is the use of $ symbol?

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, null

I wrote following line of code to filter out NULLS from a column in a dataframe

```
df = df.where(col("colname").isNotNull)
```

Is this the correct approach?
I also came across the below line of code to achieve the same result:

```
df = df.filter($"colname".isNotNull)
```

Now what i want to understand is what is the use of the **$** operator and which approach is better?
Also can I write something like this below?

```
df = df.filter(col("colname").isNotNull)
```

I'm fairly new to Scala and programming in general, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That particular usage relates to the _Spark_ library. Refer to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) for more information.

Comment: Not sure you can argue what is better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, either usage is fine, since you are not accessing a variable/value inside of a string.

I believe that the dollar sign is usually used for string interpolation. What that means is that if I want to use a val(ue)/var(iable) inside a string (denoted with an `s` before the first double quotation), I can access such vals/vars using the `$` sign. Otherwise, we won't be able to use vals/vars inside a string since it would not know how to escape the string characters.

Example:

```
val favoriteFruit = "strawberry"
val strawberryCount = 12

println(s"My favorite fruit is ${favoriteFruit}. I've had ${strawberryCount} pieces today!") // string interpolation
```

`$` can also be used as a shortcut to `getOrDefault` method. Using getOrDefault may be a more robust solution in cases in which you expect the parameter to not always have a corresponding value, for which you can set a default value. [Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/098be27ad53c485ee2fc7f5871c47f899020e87b/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala#L474) [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878340/what-does-dollar-sign-do-in-scala/58944336#58944336)

Answer (score 3):

There is a special Scala class called `StringContext`. It's used to implement various string interpolation methods, like

```
s"foo ${42}"
```

(which results in `String` `"foo 42"`), or

```
f"foo ${42}%04x"
```

(which results in a `String` with hex-formatted integers `"foo 002a"`).

The mechanism is actually quite general, and allows you to define all kinds of different string interpolation mechanisms by implicitly casting `StringContext` into your own wrapper classes. That is, if you want, you can define string interpolation mechanism that looks as follows:

```
myStringInterpolator"foo ${42}"
```

Since `$` is just an ordinary identifier, you can implement a `StringContext`-wrapper that has a method with signature

```
def $(args: Any*): YourResultType
```

and once this wrapper is in the implicit scope, you can use `$` for string interpolation as follows:

```
$"some string literal ${arg1} more text ${arg2} end"
```

and this will construct the wrapper with `StringContext` holding `["some string literal ", " more text ", " end"]`, and then invoke your `$`-method with `arg1` and `arg2`.

For example, you could define a string interpolation `$` that converts all arguments to integers and sums them up:

```
implicit class MyDollarContext(s: StringContext) {
  def $(args: Any*): Int = args.map(_.toString.toInt).sum
}

println($"I bought a coffee for ${30} and a snack for ${12}.")
```

This will print `42`, which is the sum of all numbers inside the `${...}`-braces.

Similarly, Apache Spark uses the implicit [`StringToColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits$StringToColumn) class to convert `Strings` to Spark `ColumnName`s. I'm not sure why it has been implemented in this way, I guess they wanted to make the column names look a little bit like Perl or Bash-variables, and used quite a lot of syntactic trickery for that.